# QList in classes with QT Creator/c++

Tags: c++, list, qt, qt-creator

How can I make a QList so,that this list could contain information from more than one class (the classes are operated by two Map-Containers)?

These are my 4 classes:

Class for a lecture:

```
  class Veranstaltung
    {
    private:
       QMap<QString, LV >myLV; 
    public:
    Veranstaltung() {}
    void listLV(QTextStream& out) const; 
    ...
   };

    #endif //
```

Class for the professorships

```
    LIST_H

     class ProfessurList
    {
    private:
        QMap<QString, Professur> myProfessuren; 
    public:
        ProfessurList() {} //kann man weglassen
        void addProf(QTextStream& in,QTextStream& out);
        void listProf(QTextStream& out) const; //Warum const?
       ...
    };

    #endif // PROFLIST_H
```

Another class for the lectures,where private and public are defined:

```
#ifndef LV_H
#define LV_H

class LV
{
private:
    QString myNummer;
    QString myBezeichnung;
    QString myTyp;
public:
    LV(const QString& nummer, const QString& bezeichnung, const QString& typ):
        myNummer(nummer), myBezeichnung(bezeichnung), myTyp(typ)

    {}
    QString nummer() const { return myNummer;}

    ...
};
QTextStream& operator<<(QTextStream& out, const LV& l); 

#endif // LV_H
```

Another class for the proffessorships where private and pubic are defined:

```
  #ifndef PROF_H
    #define PROF_H


    class Professur
    {
    private:
    QString myKuerzel;
    QString myName;
    QString myLehrstuhlinhaber;
    public:
    Professur(const QString& kuerzel, const QString& name, const QString& lehrstuhlinhaber):
        myKuerzel(kuerzel), myName(name), myLehrstuhlinhaber(lehrstuhlinhaber)
    {}

   ...
    };
    QTextStream& operator<<(QTextStream& out, const Professur& pr);

    #endif // PROF_H
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do, and how it relates to the code snippets you've included?

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you need to store in QList?

Comment: In order to store heterogeneous data use `QVariant`, in particular - `QVariantList`.

Comment: Thanks @kajojeq ,but I must do this with classes, I defined classes for the professorships and the lectures (3 and 4 ) and than made two map containers,where the elements should be operated (and be saved to a text file in the cpp files for the QLists), I have done this with 1 and 2,defining extra classes as QLists and this,what I still have to do: To write lectures,that are in one of the professorships and I dont know how can I reach the information of the both classes and where:in a new textfile(cpp) with QList<QString> List; or something must be defined in one of the .h files.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply create struct with X object? Like:

```
Struct ProfessorsAndLecturs
{
   Veranstaltung v;
   LEctures l;
   ...
};
ProfessorsAndLecturs pal;
pal.v = ...;
pal.l = ...;

QList<ProfessorsAndLecturs> list;
list.append(pal);
```

and later:

```
list.at(0).l;
etc.
```

If it's what you ask for.

Comment: Thanks @kajojeq ,but I must do this with classes, I defined classes for the professorships and the lectures (3 and 4 ) and than made two map containers,where the elements should be operated (and be saved to a text file in the cpp files for the QLists), I have done this with 1 and 2,defining extra classes as QLists and this,what I still have to do: To write lectures,that are in one of the professorships and I dont know how can I reach the information of the both classes and where:in a new textfile(cpp) or something must be defined in one of the .h files

Comment: @DianaPapukchieva It is kind a difficult to understand what you asking for, But I try: Maybe you need a list of lectures that has this proffesure so in proffesures.h file add `#include "LV.h"` later  `QList<LV> LectureList;` then when you add proffesure add lectures also to this list, and now you have object proffesure with list of lectures that it has. Now object has: object.lectureList; Maybe easier would be if you write whole task you need to do.

Comment: I will try so in the "LV.h", thanks a lot, I can't write my whole task, because this is a homework and I have to solve it alone, one more thime thanks. :)